# Calculating integral using Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have to evaluate  $\int _0^{2\pi} \frac {d\theta}{2+cos \theta} $ using Cauchy's integral formula. I have tried to find an $f(z)$ for $\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac {f(z)}{z-z_0}dz = f(z_0)$
 I think $\gamma$ should be a circle but I can't find $f(z)$ and $z_0$

Comment: Try the change of variables $z = e^{i\theta}$ and use De Moivre's formula.

Comment: @CheeHan can you elaborate please?

Comment: Are you talking about this - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399732/cauchys-theorem-trigonometric-application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $z=e^{i\theta}_{}$, and convert integral over $\theta$ to $\oint dz$ where the contour is a unit circle around origin in complex z-plane which can be evaluated using Cauchy method.
After few simplifications you get : 
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} d \theta \frac{1}{2+\cos\theta}=\oint_{|z|=1}^{} dz \frac{-2i}{z^2+4z+1}$$ which can be solved by Cauchy method as : 
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} d \theta \frac{1}{2+\cos\theta}=\oint_{|z|=1}^{} dz \frac{\frac{-2i}{z+2+\sqrt{3}}}{ z+2-\sqrt{3}} $$

Comment: It leads to $\frac1{2\pi i}\int_0 ^{2\pi} \frac {f(e^{i\theta}) (ie^{i\theta}) d\theta}{cos\theta + i sin\theta - z_0}$, what should I do next?

Comment: @john doe I have added a hint.

Comment: I got that, it has singularity at $-2+\sqrt3$ and $-2-\sqrt3$ one point is inside the unit circle, other is outside, but I have to use the residue theorem then. How is that using Cauchy theorem?

Comment: Yes. That's it.

Comment: But I haven't been taught residue theorem in the course

Comment: You can rephrase in terms of the formula you have given.

Comment: Hmm, got it! Residue theorem is actually equivalent to Cauchy formula. I turned denominator into a partial fraction and then applied Cauchy formula to the function at 2 points stated above to get $2\pi/\sqrt3$

Answer (score 1):

*Not an answer* strictly speaking, just a remark about real techniques, that turn out to be as effective as complex ones (maybe more) in this case.

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{2+\cos\theta}=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{2+\cos\theta} = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{2+\cos\theta}+\frac{1}{2-\cos\theta}\right)\,d\theta $$
hence:
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{2+\cos\theta}=8\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{4-\cos^2\theta}\stackrel{\theta\mapsto\arctan t}{=} 8\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{-1+4(1+t^2)}=\color{blue}{\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}}. $$

Comment: Thanks and I have got the same answer but I have to do it using Cauchy integral formula. Should I approach it like here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719994/evaluating-trigonometric-integral-and-cauchys-theorem